# Log tracepoint messages to a text file

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I've added a conditional breakpoint in a C# project along with an "Action" that writes a message to the console. Basically, when you check "Actions", you are only provided an option to "Log a message to the Output Window" (this is VS 2015).

What if I wanted to also log that message to a text file? I've been reading about trace listeners but can't figure out how to hook one up to my tracepoint.

Comment: How do you log a message? With `Trace.WriteLine()` or `Debug.WriteLine()`?

Comment: I don't log it, it is logged automatically to the output, I just specify the message in "Action" args.

Answer (score 0):

Tracepoints can only be used while debugging - since they are kept track of by the Visual Studio IDE debugger. I actually tried to set up a listener to write out the trace to a log file, but it looks like this functionality is not supported for tracepoints. But, it does work for the [Trace class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.trace(v=vs.110).aspx).

So, it looks like you are stuck with the output window while debugging. You can always copy and paste the contents of the output window to a file while debugging. If your intent was to use it for release code, then you should either use custom logging or the [Trace class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.trace(v=vs.110).aspx).

By default, the trace class writes to the output window. But, the default listener may be modified to also log Trace.WriteLine statements to a log file as well. For example:

```
using System.Diagnostics;

// Set up the log file to be the folder where the program is run from, with the name Trace.log.
DefaultTraceListener DefListener = (DefaultTraceListener)Trace.Listeners[0];
DefListener.LogFileName = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "Trace.log";
// Write out the value of Count within the loop to the log file.
for (int Loop = 0; Loop < 5; Loop++)
{
   Count++;
   Trace.WriteLine($"Count = {Count}");
}
DefListener.Flush();
```

The contents of the log file will then contain:

```
Count = 1
Count = 2
Count = 3
Count = 4
Count = 5
```

The above code works for both release and debug builds.